# Regarding PHP cut string pattern

Tags: php, html, regex

Below is my string

```
</div>
<div class="centered">Thanks for visiting</div>
<div id="related-videos">
   <div class="generic-video-item">
      <div class="thumb"><img src="http://watsite.yt/thumbnail.php?id=648p14jpgkgj" alt="" class="bg-image" /><span class="border"></span><span class="now-playing"></span><span class="video-subbed">subbed</span> <img src="http://static.cdn.animeultima.tv/images/star-trusted.png" alt="Trusted uploader" title="Trusted uploader" class="trusted" /></div>
      watsite video by <a href="/users/Argro/">Argro</a><br /><span class="time">1 hour ago</span>
   </div>
   <div class="generic-video-item">
      <div class="thumb"><a rel="nofollow" href="/Seitokai-Yakuindomo-2-episode-7-english-subbed-video-mirror-725129-watsite/"><img src="http://watsite.yt/thumbnail.php?id=4055g2gpbt2i" alt="" class="bg-image" /><span class="border"></span><span class="play"></span><span class="video-subbed">subbed</span> <img src="http://static.cdn.animeultima.tv/images/star-trusted.png" alt="Trusted uploader" title="Trusted uploader" class="trusted" /></a></div>
      watsite video by <a href="/users/Argro/">Argro</a><br /><span class="time">1 hour ago</span>
   </div>
   <div class="generic-video-item">
      <div class="thumb"><a rel="nofollow" href="/Seitokai-Yakuindomo-2-episode-7-english-subbed-video-mirror-725130-FLVUpload/"><img src="http://www.ragnaultima.com/mp4up.php?id=c56vy8likuy8" alt="" class="bg-image" /><span class="border"></span><span class="play"></span><span class="video-subbed">subbed</span> <img src="http://static.cdn.animeultima.tv/images/star-trusted.png" alt="Trusted uploader" title="Trusted uploader" class="trusted" /></a></div>
      FLVUpload video by <a href="/users/Argro/">Argro</a><br /><span class="time">1 hour ago</span>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="centered">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
```

I am trying to cut out this url

```
/Seitokai-Yakuindomo-2-episode-7-english-subbed-video-mirror-725130-FLVUpload/
```

Currently I am using the following

```
$url = inbtwn($newData,'rel="nofollow" href="','-FLVUpload/">');


function inbtwn($input, $startcut, $finishcut){
    $a1 = split($startcut, $input);
    $a2 = split($finishcut, $a1[1]);
    $output = $a2[0];
return $output;
}
```

But it return me the result with watsite,  how do I obtain this /Seitokai-Yakuindomo-2-episode-7-english-subbed-video-mirror-725130-FLVUpload/ from the chunk of string above .

**Thanks for helping**

Comment: *sidenote:* `split()` is deprecated in PHP 5.3 ; use `explode()` instead.

Comment: `$output = $a2[0].$finishcut;` ?

Comment: `$tmp = parse_url($url);
echo $tmp['path'];` it's useful :) read my answer!

Comment: @M.Eskandari how do I parse out /Seitokai-Yakuindomo-2-episode-7-english-subbed-video-mirror-725130-FLVUpload/
 from the big chunk of string?

Comment: `$array = explode("-", $url);` http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regex for a quick and dirty way

```
$regex = '/href\\s*=\\s*"([^"]*-FLVUpload\/)/s';
if  (preg_match_all($regex, $newData, $matches_out)) {
  $url = $matches_out[1][0];
  print($url);
} else {
  print('URL not found');
}
```

Comment: how do I define my $regex if I want grab /Seitokai-Yakuindomo-2-episode-7-english-subbed-video-mirror-725130-FLVUpload/

Comment: edited the answer: forgot to include single line mode

Answer (score 2):

[parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) is useful for you.

```
$url ='http://google.com/wrwetfrtgertger/';
$tmp = parse_url($url);
echo $tmp['path'];
```

or if up code not working.

```
$url ='http://google.com/wrwetfrtgertger/';
$tmp = parse_url($url);
echo $url = str_replace('http://'.$tmp['host'] ,'',$url);
```

Comment: How do I use parse to grab out the FLVUpload string?